# Parameter pack with templates

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to check is type of first template argument is same with at least one element in parameter pack, however compiler gives me an error. How can i do this?

```
template<typename TYPE, typename... x>
requires std::is_same_v<TYPE, x>...
class A
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to expand the variadic pack with a fold expression. Since you only want this to expand if *at least one* are the same, you can use `|| ...` to ensure it will resolve `true` if one of the conditions is `true`.

Also, since you are using concepts, you can also use the [`std::same_as`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/same_as) concept:

```cpp
#include <concepts>

template<typename TYPE, typename... x>
  requires (std::same_as<TYPE, x> || ...)
  //                              ^~
class A
{

};
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4r1vsMb7f)</kbd>